# syslog-ng error on CentOS, works fine on other distributions

Tags: linux, centos, syslog-ng

I want to add to a CentOS box (EL6) the same `syslog-ng` (3.2.5 from EPEL) configuration I have on other (Debian based) machines. It is intended to add events log in JSON to a single file for further processing:

```
# /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf
# (...)
source s_sys {
        file ("/proc/kmsg" program_override("kernel: "));
        unix-stream ("/dev/log");
        internal();
        # udp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(514));
};
# (...)
```

the file I add to `/etc/syslog-ng/conf.d` :

```
destination d_json { file("/var/log/all_syslog_in_json.log" perm(0666) template("{\"@timestamp\": \"$ISODATE\", \"facility\": \"$FACILITY\", \"priority\": \"$PRIORITY\", \"level\": \"$LEVEL\", \"tag\": \"$TAG\", \"host\": \"$HOST\", \"program\": \"$PROGRAM\", \"message\": \"$MSG\"}\n")); };

log { source(s_sys); destination(d_json); };
```

When starting `syslog-ng -Fevd` I get the following output upon receiving a log event:

```
Incoming log entry; line='<86>Feb  6 08:49:00 sshd[7271]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root'
Filter rule evaluation begins; filter_rule='f_kernel'
Filter node evaluation result; filter_result='not-match', filter_type='facility'
(... all the evaluations ...)
Filter node evaluation result; filter_result='not-match', filter_type='facility'
Filter rule evaluation result; filter_result='not-match', filter_rule='f_cron'
EOF occurred while reading; fd='9'
Syslog connection closed; fd='9', client='AF_UNIX(anonymous)', local='AF_UNIX(/dev/log)'
Closing log transport fd; fd='9'
```

This configuration works fine on other machines so I suppose that this is something specific to my distribution or version. I would like, however, to make sure before jumping forward (the update of syslog-ng would have to be very manual)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

syslog-ng 3.2 is very old. Newer syslog-ng versions support JSON-formatting as well.

Our package maintainer created [EPEL 6 packages for syslog-ng 3.6](https://copr.fedoraproject.org/coprs/czanik/syslog-ng36epel6/) that you can try. For details about formatting messages into JSON, see the [syslog-ng documentation](http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/reference-template-functions.html#template-function-format-json).

Regards,

Robert

Comment: Thank you, this is a life saver. I was suspecting a problem with the versions, now I know. As for the format: I saw this but need to have raw JSON logs (a JSON per line) which was not obvious to have with the built-in formatter